# How to use jquery to access highcharts piechart plotOptions: pie : size parameter?

Tags: jquery, highcharts, size, pie-chart

How to use jquery to access highcharts piechart plotOptions: pie : size parameter?
I set it as follow-

```
plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                 size: 60,
```

I need this size to be dynamically fixed, Is there a jquery to hit this variable and set it? like the setSize (that sets the whole chart size).

Comment: Check the object chart.userOptions where you keep all your defined parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

`("p").click(function(){
        var chart= $('#container').highcharts(); chart.userOptions.plotOptions.pie.size=parseInt($("#newSize").val(),10);
        $('#container').highcharts(chart.userOptions);
  });`$

demo http://jsfiddle.net/wc4p889L/2/